# Netbeans Platform Application Custormize Installer "NBI_Engine" was not found

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

Iam customizing the NPA installer to copy some external files.
I am following this tutorial ( http://netbeans.dzone.com/nb-customize-installer-to-copy-files )
 and i got some reference  problem when open the helloworld project in the harness
folder .

Problem: The project classpath includes a reference to the project called "NBI_Engine", but this project was not found.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the library nbi-engine.jar in the 
C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\harness\modules\ext folder.